# Eclipse SVN Instantly asks for Credentials

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, credentials

I know there are a lot of topics on deleting the

```
.keyring
```

file to reset this or deleting auth folder in

```
    %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth
```

but neither of these have helped me and the probem is still there. As soon as a I start up eclipse I get a prompt asking for my username and password. Even when I deleted both of those files, it still defaults to my computer login HP Admin which is wrong and not what I use.

I verified I can connect to my repo in the same environment so my credentials are correct.

As soon as I hit login, instantly another pops up asking the same thing. This will do this infinitely. I disconnected the project from the svn repo and removed the repo from my SVN Repository explorer and yet somehow it still tries to connect to it even though I can't see a single reference left in my workspace.

Any suggestions?

Comment: And if you create a new workspace? Does the problem persist? If so, I can't believe it has something to do with a lingering SVN repository. Does the popup specifically mention something to do with SVN?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid this. Unfortunately for me, I did not update after yesterday's work and got a lot done. So If i delete this, I will lose my work. The Pop up says my repo url and then says Collabent SVN

Comment: Creating a new workspace does not delete anything. You create it in a new location and can always switch back to the old one.

Comment: Just to be crystal clear: I'm not saying to delete the existing workspace, I'm saying to use the Eclipse 'switch workspace' feature to switch to a different one. Do - not - touch - any - delete - button ;)